# how to create UI which looks same across all android device regardless of its density size or screen size

Tags: android, user-interface, screen-size, screen-density

I have created UI and I want to make it independent of screen size of screen reslotuion... but I am not able to find any perfect soltution for that.

I have tried to set posiotion of view using ,
1)Displaymatrix.widthPixel and Displaymatrix.heightPixel
2)`view.measure(0,0);

  view.measureHeight();
  view.measureWidth();`
  and try to set position of view1 with respect to view... but it looks at different places on different screen size devices.
please help me to create a common UI which looks same on all size of devices.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried to achieve this in `xml`?

Comment: `dip` and `dp` should in theory be independent of device screen and use _physical_ sizes. What do you mean by same? Same physical sizes or same sizes relative to screen? If the latter you need to use a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()`

Comment: yes I have tried to achieve in xml. But it didn't work @PPartisan

Comment: with the word same ,I mean to say it should look at same place on device screen....and for that purpose I have tried to set position using x*screen width and Y*screen height... so that it looks at same place... @John